# Spin on the rack

Tags: angular-momentum, everyday-life, drag, aerodynamics, turbulence

Bike mounted on hitch rack.
Why wheels spin constantly while I drive?

I can't find anything on the internet. The kids in the other cars love to watch them

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/37785/2451

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The air flow around the car creates a vortex. There is an image of the air flow around a car:

[image]

which was used by [this earlier answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/215618/26969) - that rotating air behind the car is what spins the wheels of the bike.